# constructions of terms using variable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

It is usually said given set of variables, terms of language are defined recursively. But for recursive definition on a set, we need a function p which assigns to each function from a section of integers to T  an element of T'.
(Munkers Page 54  math.ucsb.edu/~bigelow/145/munkres.pdf )

But how we defining these function in order to generate terms

Answer (score 0):

For a formal treatment, you can see Kenneth Kunen, [The Foundations of Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=_B_oQQAACAAJ&dq) (2009), page 45 :

> **Theorem 1.9.2 (Primitive Recursion on $ON$)** Suppose that $\forall s \ \exists!y \ \varphi(s,y)$, and define $G(s)$ to be the unique $y$ such that $\varphi(s,y)$. Then we can define a formula $\psi$ for which the following are provable:
>
> > 1. $\forall x \ \exists!y \ \psi(x,y)$, so $\psi$ defines a function $F$, where $F(x)$ is the $y$ such that $\psi(x,y)$.
> > 2. $\forall \xi \in ON \ [F(\xi) = G(F \upharpoonright \xi)]$.

See page 91 :

> **Definition 11.4.1** A *lexicon* for Polish notation is a pair $(\mathcal W, \alpha)$ where $\mathcal W$ is a set of symbols and $\alpha : \mathcal W \to \omega$. Let $\mathcal W_n = \{s \in \mathcal W : \alpha(s) = n \}$. We say 
>   that the symbols in $\mathcal W_n$ have arity $n$. $\mathcal W^{< \omega}$ denotes the set of all finite sequences of symbols in $\mathcal W$. The (well-formed) expressions of $(\mathcal W, \alpha)$ are all sequences constructed by the following rule:
>
> > **(§)**  If $s \in \mathcal W_n$ and $\tau_i$ is an expression for each $i < n$, then $s \tau_1 \ldots \tau_{n-1}$ is an expression.
>
> In the "standard" applications, most of the $\mathcal W_n$ are empty. For example, we can let $\mathcal W = \{ x, y, z, !, +, . \}$, with $\mathcal W_0 = \{ x, y, z \}, \mathcal W_1 = \{ ! \}, \mathcal W_2 = \{ +, . \}$ [and thus : $\alpha(+)= \alpha(.)=2$, because $+, .$ have *arity* $2$]; the rest are empty. Then the following shows nine expressions of this lexicon:
>
> > $$x \quad y \quad z \quad +xy \quad .yz \quad +xx \quad +x.yz \quad .+xyz \quad !.+xyz$$

See page 92 :

> A symbol is really just a set, since everything is a set. We assume always that $\mathcal W \cap \mathcal W^{< \omega} = \emptyset$, and **(§)** uses the terminology of concatenation. We should also distinguish between the symbol $x \in \mathcal W_0$ and the expression of length $1$ consisting of $x$, which is set-theoretically $(x) = \{ \langle 0, x \rangle \} \in \mathcal W_1 = \mathcal W^{ \{ \emptyset \} }$. Note that the rule **(§)** is a recursive definition 
>   of the notion of "expression". To justify this definition using **Theorem 1.9.2**, recursively define $F : \omega \to \mathcal P(\mathcal W^{< \omega})$, where $F(n)$ is the set of expressions of length $\le n$.

Comment: Oh you using formula in principle of recursion and then using principle of recursion, you are defining well formed formula. Is there any problem?

Comment: @Sushil - of course, you can use the formulation adopted by Munkers (page 54) : in any case, what we get is the *unique* function $F$ (or $h$, for Munkers) that maps $0$ (or $1$) into the set of *symbols* of the alphabet, and $n$ into $F(n)$ (or $h(n)$), i.e. the set of expressions of length $≤ n$.

Comment: But we need a function which maps each section of natural no. not just each natural no.

Comment: Moreover to define section we need axiom of specification which needs wffs, again same kind of loop. We defining wff using some application of wffs

Comment: @Sushil - see above quotation form Kunen : he speaks of *ordinals*; in set theory a finite ordinal $n$ is precisely the set $\{ 0, 1, \ldots, n-1 \}$.

Comment: It only defines every natural no. contains all successor ordinals before it. But to define(or prove) n={0,1,…,n−1} we need induction. Am I right?

Comment: @Sushil - you can compare with dtldarek's answer to your previous [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356783/substituting-a-variable-in-a-formula-in-logic) : the answer is the same.

Comment: But there also I am facing some problem as I mentioned in last comment there. Please see in previous post